# Having problems with scope of variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, return, global-variables

I'm fairly new to javascript and trying to create a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors. Just for practice needs. I cant seem to figure out how to keep score. I got it so itll increment the score based off of who wins, but it resets right away. How can I get the score to save and keep adding on top of that? I apologize if anything is messy or hard to read.

```js
var computerChoice = Math.random();
var computerChoice = Math.round(computerChoice * 10);

function computer() 
{
 if(computerChoice <= 2)
 {
  computerChoice = "rock";
 }
 else if(computerChoice < 5)
 {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
 }
 else 
 {
  computerChoice = "paper";
 }
}
    

function TestFunc()
{
 computer();
 
 // Get User input
 var userChoice = document.getElementsByName('rpsOpt');
 if (userChoice[0].checked == true) 
 {
  userChoice = "rock";
 }
 else if (userChoice[1].checked == true) 
 {
  userChoice = "paper";
 }
 else if (userChoice[2].checked == true) 
 {
  userChoice = "scissors";
 }
 else 
 { 
  alert("select rock, paper or scissors");
 }
 
 // Compare Choices
 
 //Tie
 if (userChoice == computerChoice)
 {
  alert( "Your Choice: " + userChoice + "    " + "Vs."+ "    "  + "Computer Choice: " + computerChoice );
  alert("Tie!")
 }
 
 //User Rock
 else if(userChoice == "rock" && computerChoice == "scissors")
 { 
  alert( "Your Choice: " + userChoice + "    " + "Vs."+ "    "  + "Computer Choice: " + computerChoice );
  alert("You win! Rock Beats Scissors!");
  var user = document.getElementById("userScore");
  user.value++;
 }
 else if (userChoice == "rock" && computerChoice == "paper")
 {
  alert( "Your Choice: " + userChoice + "    " + "Vs."+ "    "  + "Computer Choice: " + computerChoice );
  alert("You Lose Paper Beats Rock.");
  var comp = document.getElementById("computerScore");
  comp.value++;
 }
 
 //User Paper
  else if(userChoice == "paper" && computerChoice == "rock")
 { 
  alert( "Your Choice: " + userChoice + "    " + "Vs."+ "    "  + "Computer Choice: " + computerChoice );
  alert("You win! Paper Beats Rock!");
  var user = document.getElementById("userScore");
  user.value++;
 }
 else if (userChoice == "paper" && computerChoice == "scissors")
 {
  alert( "Your Choice: " + userChoice + "    " + "Vs."+ "    "  + "Computer Choice: " + computerChoice );
  alert("You Lose Scissors Beats Paper.");
  var comp = document.getElementById("computerScore");
  comp.value++;  
 }
 
 //User Scissors
  else if(userChoice == "scissors" && computerChoice == "paper")
 { 
  alert( "Your Choice: " + userChoice + "    " + "Vs."+ "    "  + "Computer Choice: " + computerChoice );
  alert("You win! Scissors Beats Paper!");
  var user = document.getElementById("userScore");
  user.value++;  
 }
 else if (userChoice == "scissors" && computerChoice == "rock")
 {
  alert( "Your Choice: " + userChoice + "    " + "Vs."+ "    "  + "Computer Choice: " + computerChoice );
  alert("You Lose Rock Beats Scissors.");
  var comp = document.getElementById("computerScore");
  comp.value++;
 }
 

 
}
```

```css
body
{
 background: #330000;
 color: #ff0000;
}
  
.rpsBox
{
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 background-color: #333333;
 z-index: 100;
 margin-top: -200px;
 height: 400px;
 width: 600px;
 margin-left: -300px;
}

#rockBut
{
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 background-image: rock.png;
}

label > input
 {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute; 
 }
 
label > input + img
 {
 border:2px solid transparent;
 }
 
label > input:checked + img
 { 
 border:2px inset #000;
 }                     

label > input:hover + img
 { 
 border:2px inset #000;
 }                     

.score
{
 background: transparent;
 border: none;

} 
 
.button
{
 background-color: transparent;
 border: outset;
 
}

.button:hover
{
 background-color: transparent;
 border: inset;
 
}

.scoreCntr
{
 font-size: 2.4em;
 background-color: transparent;
 text-align: center;
 border-width: 0;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 .1em 0;
 color: #fff;
}

form 
{
 width: 700px;
 border:5px inset red;
 background: #fff;
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;

}

#score
{
 width: 700px;
 border:5px inset red;
 background: #aaa;
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script src="rps.js">  </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rpsStyle.css"> 

</head>


<body>

<h1> Rock, Paper, Scissors! </h1>
<div id="rbpsBox">
<form onsubmit="TestFunc()">
   <h3> Select One: </h3>
   
   <label for="rockbut">
    <input type="radio" value="rock" name="rpsOpt" id="rockbut" class="radioButton" />
    <img src="rock.png" width=150px height=150px >
   </label>

   <label for="paperbut"> 
    <input type="radio" value="paper" name="rpsOpt" id="paperbut" class="radioButton" />
    <img src="paper.jpg" width=150px height=150px >
   </label>

   <label for="scissorsbut"> 
    <input type="radio" value="scissors" name="rpsOpt" id="scissorsbut" class="radioButton" /> 
    <img src="scissors.png" width=150px height=150px > 
   </label>
    
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="GO!" class="button" > 
   <br>
   <br>
</form>
</div>

<div id="score">  

 Computer: <input type="text" class="score" id="computerScore" value=0> 
 You:  <input type="text" class="score" id="userScore" value=0>
 
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why would you need a form? and submit? submitting a form will load a new page unless you preventDefault

Comment: Add comments to code and mention me. In this present state, I can't find what is your problem

Comment: @JaromandaX he didn't mentioned `action` or `method` . So, I think it won't

Comment: Is that my problem? I'm using it as a form? So its refreshing?

Comment: That was my problem. It was refreshing cause it was a form. Thanks! Im such a noob.

Comment: @SagarV - given `<form onsubmit="TestFunc()">` ... without method and action, they default to `GET` and the current URL respectively

Comment: `Im such a noob` - seriously, forms catch a **lot** of people like this